# R - plot array like histogram

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot the values of an array in R:

```
a <- c( 276, 1591, 2367, 3441, 82, 2690, 106, 277, 172, 190, 26, 18, 32, 12, 12, 17)
```

in a form like an histogram, like this:

```
hist(a, breaks="Sturge", col="grey", labels = T,main="My array")
```

[image]

but with its value as y, instead of the frequencies.

So what I want is a simple plot:

```
plot(a, type = 'h')
```

[image]

but with a layout like the first picture (bars instead of lines).

Comment: `barplot(a)` looks pretty close.

Comment: @lmo thanks that was I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
barplot(a)
```

[image: barplot]

As @lmo mentioned, just use `barplot` instead of `plot` :)